# How to change size of box or lines in table using Latex

Tags: tables, spacing

[image: circled lines need to be corrected]

Dear all, table given in figure contains values. when i try increase the box sizes in the table the vertical line remains incomplete i.e it does not complete the box(encircled) .How i can change the length of vertical line.Please help me.Thanks a lot!Code is given below:

```
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Results} \\
    \hline

    Actual position & Estimated position & Error (mm) \\ \\ \hline

  [8.240 5.435 4.581] & [8.23997 5.43498 4.58106] & [0.00183 0.00265 0.00403]  \\ \\ \hline
  [3.322 4.512 7.365] & [3.32199 4.51198 7.36496] & [0.00912 0.01846 0.03194]  \\ \\ \hline

  [6.873 2.321 4.678] & [ 6.87299 2.32099 4.67799] & [0.00292 0.00401 0.00132]\\ \hline

[5.324 7.876 8.211] & [5.32399 7.87599 8.21099] & [0.00269 0.00631 0.00739] \\ \hline
 [3.435 6.678 4.543] & [ 3.43500 6.67800 4.54300] & [0.00163 0.00527 0.00820] \\ \hline

[5.585 7.420 2.123] & [ 5.58499 7.41999 2.12299 & [0.00056 0.00694 0.00340] \\ \hline

[8.258 4.314 6.421] & [ 8.25800 4.31399 6.42100] & [0.00774 0.00246 0.00308] \\ \hline

    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{MSE(mm) 2.359e-5} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Simulation results}
    \end{table}
    %%% end table
```

Comment: You are inserting an empty line, better use `\\[\baselinskip]`.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `\\[\normalbaselineskip`.

Comment: you have allowed two newlines on line number 6,7 and 8. Remove one newline from 6,7 and 8 line number codes and run. You will get the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would consider using `booktabs` here as it would help a lot on your table layout. Just see my example. The command you have been asking for would be `\addlinespace` here.

Please note that I have set the caption above the table as it looks quite bad on the lower side for your example. I have reduced the table width a bit by adding `@{}` but it is still 17.58 pt too wide in case you are using a two columns document. You will have to reduce that size even more then. I did not spend more work on this topic as there are many post regarding this topic on this site here.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Simulation results}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
            \toprule
            & Results & \\
            \cmidrule{2-2}          
            Actual position & Estimated position & Error (mm) \\\midrule

            [8.240 5.435 4.581] & [8.23997 5.43498 4.58106] & [0.00183 0.00265 0.00403]  \\\addlinespace  

            [3.322 4.512 7.365] & [3.32199 4.51198 7.36496] & [0.00912 0.01846 0.03194]  \\\addlinespace   

            [6.873 2.321 4.678] & [ 6.87299 2.32099 4.67799] & [0.00292 0.00401 0.00132]\\  

            [5.324 7.876 8.211] & [5.32399 7.87599 8.21099] & [0.00269 0.00631 0.00739] \\

            [3.435 6.678 4.543] & [ 3.43500 6.67800 4.54300] & [0.00163 0.00527 0.00820] \\   

            [5.585 7.420 2.123] & [ 5.58499 7.41999 2.12299 & [0.00056 0.00694 0.00340] \\

            [8.258 4.314 6.421] & [ 8.25800 4.31399 6.42100] & [0.00774 0.00246 0.00308] \\
            \midrule            
            & MSE(mm) 2.359e-5 & \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The blank lines in between are needed as the following `[...]` would be considered as an argument to `\midrule`. I would, however, recommend to set all those numbers and brackets into math-mode.

[image]